How do you make a PyQt5 Child Window with QWidget as a parent modal to the window that called it?
I'm learning PyQt5 and would like to know how to prevent the user from interacting with a parent window when a child window is called. I would like to create the QMainWindow display as a menu, perhaps showing several games the user can play. When the user clicks on the game, a new window opens and the menu is inaccessible. Is there a command for the QtWidgets.QWidget object that will make the window display modal to the calling window whether called by a QMainWindow or nested within another QWidget object?

I supposed you haven't checked the QWidget documentation yet, so I highly recommend you to do it, as it contains almost anything you're asking about.

Why does it have to be modal? Just hide the menu window before showing the game window, and vice versa.

I found the answer to my own question elsewhere. In the slot function within the QMainWindow object you would, after defining the QWidget object, write the code:
self.widget.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.WindowModality.ApplicationModal)

Applying an integer as a parameter to the self.widget.setWindowmodality(2) function worked in PyQt5 but is deprecated in PyQt6 and PySide6 therefore should be avoided as both ways work in PyQt5
